# AngularJS with Twitter Bootstrap DatePicker does not close after clicking outside

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angularjs

I'm working on a site built with Twitter Bootstrap and AngularJS.  The calendar input field pops up a calendar, which is using datepicker.  Here's the code:

```
    <div class="control-group {{errors.start_date.class}}">
      <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-small" value="{{round.start_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}" data-ng-model="round.start_date" id="start_date" onfocus="$('#start_date').datepicker({format:'mm/dd/yyyy'});$('#start_date').datepicker('show');" required>
         <span class="help-block" data-ng-show="errors.start_date">{{errors.start_date.message}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

After I select a date, I click on an area outside of the calendar pop-up, but the pop-up will not close.  I tried adding in "autoclose:'true'", as you can see in the code below, but the pop-up still will not close.

```
    <div class="control-group {{errors.start_date.class}}">
      <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="text" class="input-small" value="{{round.start_date | date:'MM/dd/yyyy'}}" data-ng-model="round.start_date" id="start_date" onfocus="$('#start_date').datepicker({format:'mm/dd/yyyy','autoclose':true});$('#start_date').datepicker('show');" required>
         <span class="help-block" data-ng-show="errors.start_date">{{errors.start_date.message}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Does anybody have any idea on how to fix this?  Actually, it would be great if the calendar pop-up will close after I click on a date as well.

Update on 2012-12-03: Previously, I had added jquery-ui-1.9.2.custom.min.js and this code to my controller:

```
$(".modal").draggable();
```

That is what disabled me from closing the calendar pop-up when clicking outside of it.  When I removed them, I am able to close the calendar.  However, I like to be able to make the modal windows draggable and close the calendar.  Is there a way to do both?  Also, I am still not able to close the calendar when I click on a date.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: There isn't quite enough information to go off of here, you can see my answer below for a suggestion but I would provide a JSFiddle demonstrating the datepicker not working if you would like more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

When including outside libraries with AngularJS you often need to wrap them in directives in order for two-way data binding & DOM events to work correctly. Docs link: [AngularJS Directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Many elements from Twitter Bootstrap and jQuery UI have already been conveniently wrapped up for you by a group of folks over at AngularUI, you can find them here: http://angular-ui.github.com/.

Here's the source code for the date directive: https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/date/date.js, AngularJS will execute the code within the `link` function after it has loaded the directive, which is where the usual datepicker event listeners are attached.

Below is some example code of how a Twitter Bootstrap form + datepicker input might look with AngularUI, where the attribute `data-ui-date` is what indicates to the AngularJS compilation process that this element is a directive. You could also leave off the `data` part and just have the attribute as `ui-date`.

```
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Start Date</label>
        <div class="controls">
            <input data-ng-model="round.start_date" data-ui-date="dateOptions" name="datepicker" type="text" class="input-medium" placeholder="">
        </div>
    </div>
```

`dateOptions` is just a scope value set somewhere in a controller or in the directive, like so:

```
    $scope.dateOptions = {
        changeYear: false,
        changeMonth: false,
        nextText: '<i class=icon-arrow-right></i>',
        prevText: '<i class=icon-arrow-left></i>',
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
    };
```

Comment: Aleross, thanks for your suggestion.  I added angular-ui.min.js to my site, added angular.module('app', ['ui']) and added your code to my template file and controller.  Your code creates the exact same calendar pop-up as what I had, and it does not close when I click on a date or outside of it.  There must be something on my site somewhere that is screwing this up, but I don't know what it might be.

Comment: Please see my "2012-12-03 Update" above in my question.